# How to customize/label the hard drive icons in the launcher

Tags: mount, launcher

Is there any way to change the hard drive icons in the launcher since I have 4 total hard drives and they all look the same. I was wondering maybe to add the LABEL of the hard drive (If exists) to the button someway or a custom icon for each. That way I know which icon is which hard drive.

An image to give an idea of my problem:

[image]

As you can see, the last 4 icons look the same.

Comment: Aren't launcher icons suppose to be labeless, with just on-hover tooltips? On the icons - USB pendrives and SD memory cards / readers get different icons so... On the other hand they get different icons based on type of the 'drive', not specific icons for specific drives. Just my loose thoughts on chances you might be getting any definitive answers on this.

Comment: It might change in the future with the many changes Unity gets. When 11.10 appeared there were many issues still with Unity, now they just solved more than 50% of them in just a month.

Comment: The previous answer (about using autorun.inf file) **doesn't work anymore** with newer versions of Ubuntu (*I'm using 14.04*).
The icon you set with this method only shows on Nautilus in a little portion of the default folder icon.
But the dash icon doesn't change...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a GoFlex which I changed the display Icon by adding two things to the hard drive.

1) Create an Image Icon or import an icon of your choice that represents your hard drive. I recommend no larger than (128 x 128 pixels) and a transparent background.

Mine is like this:

[image]

2) Name it "whatever.ico" and save it to the hard drive's "/" partition

3) Create a text file with the name "autorun.inf" and in the the file place 2 lines of text like this:

[autorun]
icon=\whatever.ico

4) save the text file to the same "/" partition.

Now this is how mine is displayed and when I take to my win7 computer it is the same there too:

[image]

Shows on the panel also.

[image]

Comment: Another great answer. Smart!.