# How can I assign custom icons to folders persistently?

Tags: nautilus, icons, filemanager

Is there some way to achieve icon persistence on Ubuntu with nautilus or some other file manager? So far when I change an icon from the properties of the folder the change won't remain visible if copied to another disk.

EDIT : I found a file `.directory` that Kubuntu had installed in my Ubuntu distro. It seems to have data about icons but I can't figure out how it works.

Comment: Asking how Windows works, is off topic. Please clarify your question to clearly state what it is you are trying to do. And don't complane that nobody has answered yet, or say that "I don't think it's possible" is an acceptable answer, when you then complain about such an answer being made.

Comment: at least for drives: http://askubuntu.com/questions/70867/how-to-customize-label-the-hard-drive-icons-in-the-launcher and I can think of a way by making a custom launcher for a hidden folder that might work ;) sit tight for a bit.

Comment: Yes this .ico for drives is exactly the type of things I want for any folder.

Comment: but not possible like that ;)

Comment: Ok I figured so. Thank you though :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this requires getting creative! For this we are going to "hack" together a .desktop file that will then launch the folder, the .desktop file can have a icon that will be the same.

1. In you Documents folder Create your folder but name it with a `.` so it will become "hidden" example `.new`
2. Find your icon example `icon.png` and put it in your folder also put a `.` in front ex `.icon.png`
3. Make a third file called `foldername.desktop`( [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop) ) open it in a editing program like `gedit` and paste this:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Link
   Terminal=false
   Icon=/home/mateo/Documents/.new/.icon.png
   Name=Folder
   URL=file:///home/mateo/Documents/.new
   ```

   but replace "mateo" with your user name for the icon and folder paths, and "Folder" with your folder name.
4. Make the `foldername.desktop` file executable - [How do I mark a file as executable via a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35478/how-do-i-mark-a-file-as-executable-via-a-gui)
5. Now to copy the folder needs to be in the same place - but the launcher can move anywhere - don't forget that the "real" folder is hidden - you can view them -> view -> show hidden files. So now you can have a folder within a drive that will be viewed the same on two different Ubuntu computers.

[image]

It wasn't easy, and most people stick with letting the theme do the job ;)

Comment: This is perfect. I'll use them for only 40+ folders so it's not as easy as the Windows method but for all intents and purposes it does the same. Thanks for the effort. How can I give you a bounty for it ? Do I have to "start a bounty"?

Comment: We should edit your answer for this reason : the `type` should be set to `Link` instead of `Application`. And therefore replace `Exec=...` with `URL=file:///home/manuel`

Comment: Awesome I kept thinking there should be a better type for the desktop file. I'll double check how that works and edit that in, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. Other operating systems cannot read the custom icons set on a folder by Nautilus or other file managers in Ubuntu. Also, the metadata system is detached from nautilus itself, so the setting for the custom icon is separate from the folder itself.

Comment: That is not what I meant, I meant is there an equivalent way for nautilus or, say, nemo to remember a folder's icon *on other* drives? Or could I achieve that through copy pasting the thumbnails stored somewhere?

Comment: Then edit your question, because it's unclear what you mean. Reading your question it sounds like you want to change the icon of a folder on a drive, and have that icon show up when you plug the drive into a different computer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14009/discussion-between-sinekonata-and-dobey)

Comment: I see now what you meant. By "other machine" I didn't mean other OS, it meant another drive or another machine with the same file manager. Also I noticed so and I was precisely looking for that metadata you speak of, do you know where it is?