# How can I set different icons for drives in dock?

Tags: icons, themes

I'm trying to figure out how to change icons for individual drives.

As you can see the last three are indistinguishable until hovered:

[image: img here]

Comment: Duplicate, but not sure if it still works, first test with LUKS+ext4 formatted drive did not, but you could try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/70867/how-to-customize-label-the-hard-drive-icons-in-the-launcher

Comment: @pLumo tried that first but not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use `x-gvfs-icon` in `/etc/fstab`

The trick with `autorun.inf` suggested by *pLumo* seems not to work anymore, but one can set icons via the `x-gvfs-icon` option in `/etc/fstab`.

For this option only icons that are provided through an icon theme can be used.

### Set `x-gvfs-icon` with gnome-disks

If you want to be on the safe side, make a backup copy of your `/etc/fstab` first:

```sh
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup
```

Open `gnome-disks` (it is under *Activities -> Utilities - Disks*). Find the partition for which you want to change the icon, select it (it must be highlighted) and click on the gear icon ("*Additional partition options*").

In the menu, that pops up select "*Edit Mount Options...*".

In the dialog you must first switch off "*User Session Defaults*". Then under "*Icon Name*" you can place a name known to the icon theme. For a first test you could put `gnome-cd`, which will get you an CD-icon. How to find icon names and how to add custom ones I will explain in the following two sections.

Before clicking "*OK*", ensure yourself, that the other options are correct, for example "*Mount at system startup*". When you click "OK", enter your password, which will then save those settings in `/etc/fstab`. Usually `gnome-disks` provides you with good default options, but still you have to **handle them with care**.

The new entry in `/etc/fstab` that has been created for us could for example look like this:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/<the-uuid> /mnt/<the-uuid> auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-icon=<name-of-the-icon>,noauto 0 0
```

[image: gnome-disks]

### Find some icon names in the theme

Icons are located under `/usr/share/icons/<theme-name>/<size>/<topic>`, so for example to look up 48x48 device icons in the Yaru theme one can do:

```
ls /usr/share/icons/Yaru/48x48/devices/
```

The name for `x-gvfs-icon` is simply without the file ending.

### How to create a small custom icon theme

This are a few steps to create custom icons that can be used for `x-gvfs-icon` option.

I assume in this description that you have put an icon called `mydrive.png` into `~/Downloads`. Formats accepted are PNG or SVG, ICO did not work for me. The size should be somewhere between 32 and 128 pixels for PNG.

1. prepare the folders

   ```sh
   sudo bash
   cd /usr/share/icons/
   mkdir -p custom/any/devices
   ```

   I assume that you do not want to maintain different sizes, so I just used `any` for the size.
2. create the index.theme file

   ```sh
   nano custom/index.theme
   ```

   and put the following content into it:

   ```sh
   [Icon Theme]
   Name=Custom
   Comment=Icons added by the user
   Directories=any/devices

   [any/devices]
   Context=Devices
   Size=48
   Type=Fixed
   ```

   Note that the "Size" parameter is just a hint for GTK, the actual size of the file can differ.
3. copy a new icon

   ```sh
   cp ~/Downloads/mydrive.png /usr/share/icons/custom/any/devices
   ```
4. link to the new theme from existing themes

   Here if you are using different theme now, you must replace `Yaru` with the name of your theme. I edit `Humanity` here too, because it is a fallback for many themes.

   Edit (`nano ...` or `gedit ...`) the files

   ```
   /usr/share/icons/Yaru/index.theme
   /usr/share/icons/Humanity/index.theme
   ```

   and add `...,custom` to the `Inherits=` option.
   That gives for Yaru:

   ```
   Inherits=Humanity,hicolor,custom
   ```

   and for Humanity:

   ```
   Inherits=Adwaita,hicolor,custom
   ```

   Exit the super user bash with `exit`.

Done! Now the name `mydrive` can be used as "Icon Name" in gnome-disks!

After copying new icons, a restart of Gnome (logoff + logon) might be required!

Comment: thank you sir it worked